# Is it possible to extract the rearrangement map from OrderBy?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I have a list of a class called "banana" like this

```
Class Banana
    Public Ripeness as single
End Class

Dim bananas as new List(of Banana)
```

And now I need a list of indices that order the bananas by their ripeness so if the banana list goes like this:

```
(0) .Ripeness = 2
(1) .Ripeness = 1
(2) .Ripeness = 5
```

Then the integer list should be "1, 0, 2". I don't actually need to reorder the banana list itself, it is important that it stays in the same order.

Right now I'm getting the list by scanning through the entire list of bananas for the next lowest ripeness and adding the index to the integer list. The problem with that is that its slow (there are thousands of bananas), using the built in OrderBy function reorders the objects 7 times quicker than I can produce the index list. Is there a way to get the mapping that OrderBy applies to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
bananas.Select((i, banana) => select new { Index=i, Banana=banana})
       .OrderBy(x => x.Banana)
       .Select((newIndex, x) => new { NewIndex=newIndex, x.Index})
       .OrderBy(x => x.Index)
       .Select(x=> x.NewIndex)
       .ToList();
```

If that's what you're looking for, the process is called "finding the ranks of elements"

Comment: That's clever. Like it!